# Use a Stored Procedure Parameter in Join Condition only when it is not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote a Stored Procedure where i need to Filter records based on passed Parameter.

```
Create Procedure spGetName_User_Information 
    @USER VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NoCount ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering With Select statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    Select val.userName, val.validFrom, val.validUpto, val.totalPoints, per.senderID
    from userValidity as val
    Inner Join Persons  as per

    --When @USER in Empty then use this join condition
    on val.username = per.userName

    --When @USER in Not Empty then use this join condition
    on val.username = per.userName AND per.userName in (@User)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

My Requirement is filter records in join Condition based on passed parameter i.e., if Parameter is empty join condition should not filter based on parameter but if parameter is not empty then i should use that parameter to filter records in join condition.

NOTE: I have to use Passed parameter in join condition only, i cannot use it in WHERE, HAVING condition in the Select. It should be used only in JOIN "ON" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Create Procedure spGetName_User_Information 
    @USER VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NoCount ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering     With Select statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    Select val.userName, val.validFrom, val.validUpto, val.totalPoints, per.senderID
    from userValidity as val
    Inner Join Persons  as per

    on ((ISNULL(@User,'') = '') AND (val.username = per.userName)) OR
       ((ISNULL(@User,'') <> '') AND (val.username = per.userName) AND (per.userName in (@User))

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Create Procedure spGetName_User_Information 
    @USER VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NoCount ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering With Select statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ExecQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @ExecQuery = 'Select val.userName, val.validFrom, val.validUpto, val.totalPoints, per.senderID
    from userValidity as val Inner Join Persons  as per'

    --When @USER in Empty then use this join condition
    IF ISNULL(@USER,'') = ''
      SET @ExecQuery = @ExecQuery + ' on val.username = per.userName'
    ELSE IF ISNULL(@USER,'') <> ''  
    --When @USER in Not Empty then use this join condition
    SET @ExecQuery = @ExecQuery + ' on val.username = per.userName AND per.userName in (@User)'

    EXEC (@ExecQuery)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: You should get an error "Must declare the scalar variable "@User""

Comment: This is ok, but in Actual scenario i cannot use a new Varchar variable bcoz i have length Stored Procedure with Multiple Join Condition

Comment: You concatenate query then only you get your expected result.So you must declare for concatenate

Answer (score 0):

You could manage null in your procedure as :

```
Create Procedure spGetName_User_Information 
    @USER VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
Set @USER = case when @USER is null then null when ltrim(rtrim( @USER )) = '' then null else @USER end

    -- SET NoCount ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering With Select statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    Select val.userName, val.validFrom, val.validUpto, val.totalPoints, per.senderID
    from userValidity as val
    Inner Join Persons  as per
    on val.username = per.userName 
    and per.userName = Isnull(@User, per.userName)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: No Where Condition should be used

Comment: you can remove the where & put it in join. it wont matter

Comment: I Appriciate your work, and thanks for coming with so many variation with the Query.